# How to inject template using slot with data-binding in Polymer2

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x

I'd like to inject a rendering template from a parent component to a child component using `<slot>` insertion points. The injected template contains data-binding on a property of the child component (`my-child.data` in this case).

```
<dom-module id="my-parent">
  <template>
    <my-child>
      <template>
        <div>Child's data property: [[data]]</div>
      </template>
    </my-child>
  </template>
  ...
```

The rendering child component basically looks like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-child">
  <template>
    <header></header>
    <slot></slot>
    <footer></footer>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyChild extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-child'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          data: { ... }
        };
      }
      ...
```

I'm not sure whether this is possible at all with Polymer2. Vue2 has a concept called ["scoped slot"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots) to achieve this. Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Comment: I think this is not possible since the `[[data]]` within the `<my-parent>` component template is always referred to itself and not the `<my child>` element. Also I think there isn't a "scoped slot" Vue-like in Polymer 2. Why can't you print the `[[data]]` directly inside your child component?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The reason for injecting a template is, that `[[data]]` can be wrapped by various tags, e.g. `<strong>[[data]]</strong>` or `<code>[[data]]</code>` and I wanted to avoid distinct custom elements for each possibility or having `dom-if` blocks in the `my-child` component being based on input properties to that component.
In Polymer's legacy layer I still find `templatizer-behavior` which seems to be deprecated. However I did not find any documentation about migration from Polymer 1.x to Polymer 2.x for template stamping.

Comment: This is also possible in Polymer. It is true, that the bindings are always scoped to the current scope - but you can use a `template` and stamp it in a different scope. Your `my-parent` element actually has the contents of the `my-child` inside a `template` element, which means you only need to stamp the template inside your `my-child`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Data binding is by default tied within the current scope of the binding. If you wish to change the scope, you must put your markup inside a `<template>` tag and stamp in it inside a different scope.

Your HTML code in the question is already OK - you actually wrap the light DOM inside a `<template>`, but you then use that `<template>` incorrectly. You must *not* use `<slot>`, but must stamp that template manually and insert it somewhere inside the `my-child` element's shadow DOM.

Here you have a working demo on how to achieve this: http://jsbin.com/loqecucaga/1/edit?html,console,output

I have even added the `data` property binding to an `input` element in order to demonstrate that property changes also affect the stamped template.

The stamping is relatively simple and is done inside the `connectedCallback` method:

```
var template = this.querySelector('template');
this.__instance = this._stampTemplate(template);
this.$.content.appendChild(this.__instance);
```

The stamped template is put inside a placeholder `div` element, which you put somewhere inside the `my-child`'s template:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

To sum up, here is the full code from the demo:

```
<link href="polymer/polymer-element.html" rel="import"/>
<link href="polymer/lib/mixins/template-stamp.html" rel="import"/>

<dom-module id="my-parent">
  <template>
    <my-child>
      <template>
        <div>Child's data property: [[data]]</div>
      </template>
    </my-child>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyParent extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-parent'; }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyParent.is, MyParent);
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="my-child">
  <template>
    <header>Header</header>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
    <input type="text" value="{{data::input}}" />
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyChild extends Polymer.TemplateStamp(Polymer.Element) {
      static get is() { return 'my-child'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          data: {
            type: String,
            value: 'Hello, World!'
          },
        };
      }

      connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();

        var template = this.querySelector('template');
        this.__instance = this._stampTemplate(template);
        this.$.content.appendChild(this.__instance);
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyChild.is, MyChild);
  </script>
</dom-module>

<my-parent></my-parent>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, which sounds reasonable not to fiddle around with the shadow DOM of `<slot>` directly. Just tested, works like a charm with data-binding - perfect!